# Taking multiple string arrays and write it into one single line print

Tags: java

I was wondering if it's possible to print the results from all the string arrays into one single println instead of multiple.

```
    String[] test1 = { "a", "b", "c" };  
    String[] test2 = { "a", "B", "c", "D", "e" }; 
    String[] test3 = { "A", "B", "C", "D" };  
    String[] test4 = { "$", "B", "c", "6", "D", "\n", "E" };  

    int upperCaseCount1 = countUppercase(test1); //Instead of printing this
    System.out.println(upperCaseCount1);
    int upperCaseCount2 = countUppercase(test2);
    System.out.println(upperCaseCount2); 
    int upperCaseCount3 = countUppercase(test3);
    System.out.println(upperCaseCount3);
    int upperCaseCount4 = countUppercase(test4);
    System.out.println(upperCaseCount4);

    //am i able to use a single line print? like....my failed attempts here.
    System.out.println(countUppercase("test1", "test2","test3", "test4");
```

Comment: What is the implementation of your `countUppercase` method?

Comment: `System.out.println(""+upperCaseCount1 + " " + uppercaseCount2 + " " +...);`

Comment: public static int countUppercase(String arr[]){
        int count = 0;
        for(int i = 0;i<arr.length;i++){
            if(arr[i].charAt(0) >= 'A' && arr[i].charAt(0) <= 'Z'){
                count++;
            }
        }
        return count;
    }


}

Comment: Well, clearly you can't pass all of your arrays at once to `countUppercase`.  But even if you _could_, the correct way would have been `countUppercase(test1, test2,...)`, not `countUppercase("test1", "test2",...)`.  Once you put quotes around a variable name, it's not a variable name any more, just a `String`.

Comment: You're right kevin. I tried a few ways and it didn't work. So I thought I'd ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can concatenate the results in println

```
int upperCaseCount1 = countUppercase(test1);
int upperCaseCount2 = countUppercase(test2);
int upperCaseCount3 = countUppercase(test3);
int upperCaseCount4 = countUppercase(test4);

System.out.println( upperCaseCount1 +", "+upperCaseCount2 +", "+upperCaseCount3 +", "+upperCaseCount4);
```

if you can use printf instead you can also do something like this:

```
System.out.printf( "Results: %d, %d, %d, %d%n", upperCaseCount1, upperCaseCount2, upperCaseCount3, upperCaseCount4);
```

%d is for int, %n is new line. [simple tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/numberformat.html).

you can also use StringBuilder. [tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/buffers.html).

```
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder("Results: ");
builder.append(countUppercase(test1)).appende(" ").
    append(countUppercase(test2)).appende(" ").
    append(countUppercase(test3)).appende(" ").
    append(countUppercase(test4));
System.out.println( builder);
```